# Blogdown: cannot see latest post in recent posts

Tags: r, blogdown

I've published my blog to netlify: https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com

Github: https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz

I've created a new post today: 4/26/2019.

I can acces the blog section:

https://affectionate-allen-e5fa8f.netlify.com/blog/

But I cannot see my post. It has the date of today.

> Do I need to hardcode this?

Rmd file:

````
---
title: "react-class-based-components"
author: "omar gonzales diaz"
date: "4/26/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
````

**HUGO version: 0.24.**

**permalinks in configuration.toml**

```
[Permalinks]
    blog = "/blog/:year/:month/:day/:filename/"
```

**date format in configuration.toml**

```
Format dates with Go's time formatting
    date_format = "January 2, 2006"
```

**configuration.toml**

```
baseurl = "/"
title = "omargonzalesdiaz"
theme = "hugo-universal-theme"
languageCode = "es-es"
# Site language. Available translations in the theme's `/i18n` directory.
defaultContentLanguage = "es"
# Enable comments by entering your Disqus shortname
disqusShortname = "omargonzalesdiaz"
# Enable Google Analytics by entering your tracking code
googleAnalytics = "UA-54695178-1"

# Define the number of posts per page
paginate = 10

[menu]

# Main menu

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Inicio"
    url  = "/"
    weight = 1

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Blog"
    url  = "/blog/"
    weight = 2


[[menu.main]]
    name = "contacto"
    url  = "/contacto/"
    weight = 4

# Top bar social links menu

[[menu.topbar]]
    weight = 1
    name = "GitHub"
    url = "https://github.com/devcows/hugo-universal-theme"
    pre = "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-github'></i>"


[[menu.topbar]]
    weight = 3
    name = "Twitter"
    url = "http://twitter.com"
    pre = "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter'></i>"

[[menu.topbar]]
    weight = 4
    name = "Email"
    url = "mailto:oma.gonzales@gmail.com"
    pre = "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-envelope'></i>"

[params]
    viewMorePostLink = "/blog/"
    author = "DevCows"
    defaultKeywords = ["devows", "hugo", "go"]
    defaultDescription = "Site template made by devcows using hugo"

    # Twitter
    twitter = "GoHugoIO"
    twitterImage = "img/twitter-default.png"

    # Google Maps API key (if not set will default to not passing a key.)
    googleMapsApiKey = "AIzaSyCFhtWLJcE30xOAjcbSFi-0fnoVmQZPb1Y"

    # Style options: default (light-blue), blue, green, marsala, pink, red, turquoise, violet
    style = "blue"

    # Since this template is static, the contact form uses www.formspree.io as a
    # proxy. The form makes a POST request to their servers to send the actual
    # email. Visitors can send up to a 1000 emails each month for free.
    #
    # What you need to do for the setup?

    # - set your email address under 'email' below
    # - upload the generated site to your server
    # - send a dummy email yourself to confirm your account
    # - click the confirm link in the email from www.formspree.io
    # - you're done. Happy mailing!
    #
    # Enable the contact form by entering your Formspree.io email
    email = "your@email.com"
    contact_form_ajax = false

    about_us = "<p>Página personal de omargonzalesdiaz.</p>"
    copyright = "Copyright (c) 92019, omargonzalesdiaz; todos los derechos reservados."

    # Format dates with Go's time formatting
    date_format = "January 2, 2006"

    logo = "img/logo.png"
    logo_small = "img/logo-small.png"
    address = """<p><strong>Lima - Perú</strong>""" 


[Permalinks]
    blog = "/blog/:year/:month/:day/:filename/"

# Enable or disable top bar with social icons
[params.topbar]
    enable = true
    text = """<p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Contact us on +420 777 555 333 or hello@universal.com.</p>
      <p class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
      <a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </p>
      """

# Enable and disable widgets for the right sidebar
[params.widgets]
    categories = true
    tags = true
    search = true

[params.carousel]
    enable = true
    # All carousel items are defined in their own files. You can find example items
    # at 'exampleSite/data/carousel'.
    # For more informtion take a look at the README.

[params.features]
    enable = true
    # All features are defined in their own files. You can find example items
    # at 'exampleSite/data/features'.
    # For more informtion take a look at the README.

[params.testimonials]
    enable = false
    # All testimonials are defined in their own files. You can find example items
    # at 'exampleSite/data/testimonials'.
    # For more informtion take a look at the README.
    title = "Testimonials"
    subtitle = "We have worked with many clients and we always like to hear they come out from the cooperation happy and satisfied. Have a look what our clients said about us."

[params.see_more]
    enable = true
    icon = "fa fa-file-code-o"
    title = "Do you want to see more?"
    subtitle = "We have prepared for you more than 40 different HTML pages, including 5 variations of homepage."
    link_url = "#"
    link_text = "Check other homepages"

[params.clients]
    enable = false
    # All clients are defined in their own files. You can find example items
    # at 'exampleSite/data/clients'.
    # For more informtion take a look at the README.
    title = "Our Clientss"
    subtitle = ""

[params.recent_posts]
    enable = true
    title = "Del Blog"
    subtitle = "Entradas más recientes."
```

Comment: I don't see an html file in "content" that I would expect from a blogdown website (it's possible this is theme dependent). This file is created when you serve the site (I use the Addin "Serve site" in RStudio but you can also do `blogdown::serve_site()`).  You can see [on my blog repo](https://github.com/aosmith16/aosmith/tree/master/content/post) that I have both RMD and html files for every post.  Also, not necessarily related, you'll eventually want to change your `basurl` in `config.toml` to the URL of your website.

Comment: @aosmith yes. I had to run `blogdown::serve_site()` to generate the html files. Now my post appears. Also,  I had to change the date format from `date: "4/26/2019"` to `date: '2019-04-26'`. Please submitt and answer, it could be of help for future readersl explaining why the date format matters. I'm guessing is something related to Hugo.

Comment: I'm also getting my dates in english, don't know why...I'd appreaciate also your help with this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure on the dates.  So far all I've found about customizing dates in Hugo is [here](https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#customize-dates).  You may want to ask another question and see if any other folks have any ideas.  If you know of someone with a blogdown blog in another language you could take a look at their repo to see what it looks like (that's often how I figure stuff out for blogdown :-D).

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct on needing dates with international standard notation.  I didn't catch that.  You should feel free to put in your own answer to your question if that was part of what was going on.